# how to make custom class in fabric js using fabric.Textbox Class override?

Tags: button, textbox, fabricjs

1. I am using FabricJS version : 3.6.3
2. I want to make new FabricJS class called : Button
3. So that I have extend one class called `Textbox` from fabric js, which will **Draw** a `Rectangle` behind `Text` and it looking like a button.
4. But Problem is that, I can't set `height` to that `Button` because `height` is not allow in `Texbox` object.
5. I want to set `Height` and `Width` to `Button` object. `Width` is working Properly due to `Textbox`. it will also warp Text if width keep smaller then text width, and can be editable by double clicking on it. But only problem is that can't set `Height` to an `object`
6. it should be `Text vertically center` when `Height` is increase.

In short I want to make this kind of functionality in fabric js using object customization.

**Expected Output :**

[image]

but **Actual Output :**

[image]

Here Is my Code That Create button :

```js
// fabric js custom button class
(function (fabric) {
  "use strict";

  // var fabric = global.fabric || (global.fabric = {});

  fabric.Button = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
    type: "button",
    stateProperties: fabric.Object.prototype.stateProperties.concat(
      "buttonRx",
      "buttonRy",
      "buttonFill",
      "buttonPadding",
      "buttonStrokeColor",
      "buttonStrokeWidth"
    ),
    buttonRx: 0,
    buttonRy: 0,
    buttonFill: "#ffffff00",
    buttonPadding: 0,
    buttonHeight: 0,
    buttonWidth: 0,
    textAlign: "center",
    buttonStrokeColor: "#000000",
    buttonStrokeWidth: 0,
    _dimensionAffectingProps: fabric.Text.prototype._dimensionAffectingProps.concat(
      "width",
      "fontSize"
    ),
    cacheProperties: fabric.Object.prototype.cacheProperties.concat(
      "buttonRx",
      "buttonRy",
      "buttonFill",
      "buttonPadding",
      "buttonStrokeColor",
      "buttonStrokeWidth"
    ),
    initialize: function (text, options) {
      this.text = text;
      this.callSuper("initialize", text, options);
      /* this.on("scaling", function () {
        console.log('scaling', this.getScaledHeight());
        
        this.set({
          height: this.getScaledHeight(),
          scaleY: 1,
        });
      }); */

      this._initRxRy();
    },

    _initRxRy: function () {
      if (this.buttonRx && !this.buttonRy) {
        this.buttonRy = this.buttonRx;
      } else if (this.buttonRy && !this.buttonRx) {
        this.buttonRx = this.buttonRy;
      }
    },
    /* _setCenter(){

    }, */
    _render: function (ctx) {
      // 1x1 case (used in spray brush) optimization was removed because
      // with caching and higher zoom level this makes more damage than help
      // this.width = this.width * this.scaleX;
      // this.height = this.height * this.scaleY;
      // (this.scaleX = 1), (this.scaleY = 1);
      var rx = this.buttonRx ? Math.min(this.buttonRx, this.width / 2) : 0,
        ry = this.buttonRy ? Math.min(this.buttonRy, this.height / 2) : 0,
        w = this.width + this.buttonPadding,
        h = this.height + this.buttonPadding,
        x = -this.width / 2 - this.buttonPadding / 2,
        y = -this.height / 2 - this.buttonPadding / 2,
        isRounded = rx !== 0 || ry !== 0,
        /* "magic number" for bezier approximations of arcs (http://itc.ktu.lt/itc354/Riskus354.pdf) */
        k = 1 - 0.5522847498;
      ctx.beginPath();

      ctx.moveTo(x + rx, y);

      ctx.lineTo(x + w - rx, y);
      isRounded &&
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + w - k * rx, y, x + w, y + k * ry, x + w, y + ry);

      ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h - ry);
      isRounded &&
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
          x + w,
          y + h - k * ry,
          x + w - k * rx,
          y + h,
          x + w - rx,
          y + h
        );

      ctx.lineTo(x + rx, y + h);
      isRounded &&
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + k * rx, y + h, x, y + h - k * ry, x, y + h - ry);

      ctx.lineTo(x, y + ry);
      isRounded && ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, y + k * ry, x + k * rx, y, x + rx, y);

      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.save();
      if (this.buttonFill) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.buttonFill;
        if (this.fillRule === "evenodd") {
          ctx.fill("evenodd");
        } else {
          ctx.fill();
        }
      }
      if (this.buttonStrokeWidth > 0) {
        if (this.strokeUniform) {
          ctx.scale(1 / this.scaleX, 1 / this.scaleY);
        }
        if (this.shadow && !this.shadow.affectStroke) {
          this._removeShadow(ctx);
        }
        if (this.buttonStrokeColor) {
          ctx.lineWidth = this.buttonStrokeWidth;
          ctx.strokeStyle = this.buttonStrokeColor;
          ctx.stroke();
        } else {
          ctx.lineWidth = this.buttonStrokeWidth;
          ctx.stroke();
        }
      }
      ctx.restore();

      this.clearContextTop();
      this._clearCache();
      this.height = this.calcTextHeight();
      this.saveState({ propertySet: "_dimensionAffectingProps" });
      //   this._renderPaintInOrder(ctx);

      this._setTextStyles(ctx);
      this._renderTextLinesBackground(ctx);
      this._renderTextDecoration(ctx, "underline");
      this._renderText(ctx);
      this._renderTextDecoration(ctx, "overline");
      this._renderTextDecoration(ctx, "linethrough");
      this.initDimensions();
      // this.callSuper('render', ctx);
    },
    toObject: function (propertiesToInclude) {
      return this.callSuper(
        "toObject",
        [
          "buttonRx",
          "buttonRy",
          "buttonFill",
          "buttonPadding",
          "buttonStrokeColor",
          "buttonStrokeWidth",
          "objectCaching",
        ].concat(propertiesToInclude)
      );
    },
  });

  fabric.Button.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
    return fabric.Object._fromObject("Button", object, callback, "text");
  };
})(fabric);

// fabric js class finish here


var canvas = [];
var cotainer = document.getElementById("canvas-container");
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  var width = 500,
    height = 500;
  var canvasEl = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvasEl.id = "canvas-" + i;
  cotainer.append(canvasEl);
  var fabCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasEl, {});
  fabCanvas.setHeight(height);
  fabCanvas.setWidth(width);
  canvas.push(fabCanvas);
}

canvas.forEach((c) => {
  var button = new fabric.Button("Click Me", {
    text: "Click Me",
    buttonStrokeColor: "#f00",
    buttonStrokeWidth: 2,
    width: 110,
    fill: "#f00",
    fontSize: 50,
    width: 400,
    buttonFill: "#42A5F5",
    buttonRx: 15,
    buttonRy: 15,
    objectCaching: false,
    fontFamily: "verdana",
  });
  c.add(button);
  c.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas{
border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.2/fabric.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-container">
</div>
```

Comment: meybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633710/resize-fabric-rect-without-resizing-textbox can help you

Comment: Thanks A lot for Reply. I will try to solve it .

Comment: Thanks a Lot, I have added padding of 50 in the above example,  but the selection handled only covers the textbox and not include padded area. ?? how can I fix that ?? https://codepen.io/pramit-sawant/pen/poexoav  here is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will be to set the scaleX and scaleY of the button text to 1 when you scale the Button Object and also set the font size of the text equal to its scale.

Comment: Thanks for reply Buddy. It will help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tbox = new fabric.Button(v.textDisp, {
    left: v.posX,
    top: v.posY,
    boxHeight: v.length // new create
});

 fabric.Button = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
    type: "button",
    stateProperties: fabric.Object.prototype.stateProperties.concat(
      "buttonRx",
      "buttonRy",
      "buttonFill",
      "buttonPadding",
      "buttonStrokeColor",
      "buttonStrokeWidth",
      "boxHeight"
    ),
    buttonRx: 0,
    buttonRy: 0,
    buttonPadding: 0,
    buttonHeight: 0,
    buttonWidth: 0,
    buttonStrokeColor: "#000000",
    buttonStrokeWidth: 0,
    _dimensionAffectingProps: fabric.Text.prototype._dimensionAffectingProps.concat(
      "width",
      "fontSize"
    ),
    cacheProperties: fabric.Object.prototype.cacheProperties.concat(
      "buttonRx",
      "buttonRy",
      "buttonFill",
      "buttonPadding",
      "buttonStrokeColor",
      "buttonStrokeWidth",
      "boxHeight"
    ),
    initialize: function (text, options) {
      this.text = text;
      this.callSuper("initialize", text, options);
      /* this.on("scaling", function () {
        console.log('scaling', this.getScaledHeight());
        
        this.set({
          height: this.getScaledHeight(),
          scaleY: 1,
        });
      }); */

      this._initRxRy();
    },

    _initRxRy: function () {
      if (this.buttonRx && !this.buttonRy) {
        this.buttonRy = this.buttonRx;
      } else if (this.buttonRy && !this.buttonRx) {
        this.buttonRx = this.buttonRy;
      }
    },
    /* _setCenter(){

    }, */
    _render: function (ctx) {
      // 1x1 case (used in spray brush) optimization was removed because
      // with caching and higher zoom level this makes more damage than help
      // this.width = this.width * this.scaleX;
      // this.height = this.height * this.scaleY;
      // (this.scaleX = 1), (this.scaleY = 1);
      
      var rx = this.buttonRx ? Math.min(this.buttonRx, this.width / 2) : 0,
        ry = this.buttonRy ? Math.min(this.buttonRy, this.height / 2) : 0,
        w = this.width + this.buttonPadding,
        h = this.height + this.buttonPadding,
        x = -this.width / 2 - this.buttonPadding / 2,
        y = -this.height / 2 - this.buttonPadding / 2,
        hh = this.boxHeight * this.scaleY,
        isRounded = rx !== 0 || ry !== 0,
        k = 1 - 0.5522847498;
      ctx.beginPath();
      
      
        
      ctx.moveTo(x + rx, y);

      ctx.lineTo(x + w - rx, y);
      isRounded &&
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + w - k * rx, y, x + w, y + k * ry, x + w, y + ry);

      ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + hh - ry);
      isRounded &&
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(
          x + w,
          y + hh - k * ry,
          x + w - k * rx,
          y + hh,
          x + w - rx,
          y + hh
        );

      ctx.lineTo(x + rx, y + hh);
      isRounded &&
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + k * rx, y + hh, x, y + hh - k * ry, x, y + hh - ry);

      ctx.lineTo(x, y + ry);
      isRounded && ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, y + k * ry, x + k * rx, y, x + rx, y);

      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.save();
      if (this.buttonFill) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.buttonFill;
        if (this.fillRule === "evenodd") {
          ctx.fill("evenodd");
        } else {
          ctx.fill();
        }
      }
      if (this.buttonStrokeWidth > 0) {
        if (this.strokeUniform) {
          ctx.scale(1 / this.scaleX, 1 / this.scaleY);
        }
        if (this.shadow && !this.shadow.affectStroke) {
          this._removeShadow(ctx);
        }
        if (this.buttonStrokeColor) {
          ctx.lineWidth = this.buttonStrokeWidth;
          ctx.strokeStyle = this.buttonStrokeColor;
          ctx.stroke();
        } else {
          ctx.lineWidth = this.buttonStrokeWidth;
          ctx.stroke();
        }
      }
      ctx.restore();
      this.clearContextTop();
      this._clearCache();
      
      this.height = this.calcTextHeight();
      this.saveState({ propertySet: "_dimensionAffectingProps" });
      //   this._renderPaintInOrder(ctx);

      this._setTextStyles(ctx);
      this._renderTextLinesBackground(ctx);
      this._renderTextDecoration(ctx, "underline");
      this._renderText(ctx);
      this._renderTextDecoration(ctx, "overline");
      this._renderTextDecoration(ctx, "linethrough");
      this.initDimensions();
      // this.callSuper('render', ctx);
    },
    toObject: function (propertiesToInclude) {
      return this.callSuper(
        "toObject",
        [
          "buttonRx",
          "buttonRy",
          "buttonFill",
          "buttonPadding",
          "buttonStrokeColor",
          "buttonStrokeWidth",
          "objectCaching",
          "boxHeight"
        ].concat(propertiesToInclude)
      );
    },
  });

After adding boxHeight, declare a variable as 'hh' instead of'h' in "_render" When drawing, change to'hh' instead of'h'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.